# How to mention a discord channel in an embed message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In the description of my embed, I would like where `#channel` is written to be replaced with the mention of the channel. I would like to get this channel object through its id; however, I do not know how to do so.

```py
@bot.command() 
async def whois(ctx, member : discord.Member):  
  embed = discord.Embed(title = "**__Soporte general usando tickets__**",
  description= "**To create a ticket, run `!New` in #channel \nPara pedir ayuda deberías utilizar el siguiente formato:\n",
  color=discord.Color.blue())
  embed.set_footer(text="ADN Development")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `bot.get_channel(id)`. Try this out:

```py
@bot.command() 
async def whois(ctx, member : discord.Member):
  channel = bot.get_channel(id)  
  embed = discord.Embed(title = "**__Soporte general usando tickets__**" , description= f"**To create a ticket, run `!New` in {channel.mention}\nPara pedir ayuda deberías utilizar el siguiente formato:\n", color=discord.Color.blue())
  embed.set_footer(text="ADN Development")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: but where do I put the channel id?

Comment: @JesusGFX Oh, you want to use channel id? You didn't mention that in your question. I've edited my code. Try the new code.

Comment: module 'discord' has no attribute 'get_channel'

Comment: @JesusGFX no no, look at my code again. I changed it from `discord` to `bot`. Copy the code exactly and try it again.

Comment: it worked but the channel does not appear type appears as: {channel.mention}

Comment: @JesusGFX Make sure you have the `f` before the string. So, like this: description= `f"**To create a ticket, run !New in {channel.mention}\nPara pedir ayuda deberías utilizar el siguiente formato:\n"`

Comment: @JesusGFX make sure to click the accept button below the downvote button next to my post if this helped you out!